# Reserve vector elements in a class

Tags: c++

I have C++ code with a simple class:

```
class SimpleClass {
    public:
        std::vector<int> MyVectorOfInts;
}
```

And when I try to reserve elements for that vector:

```
MyVectorOfInts.reserve(10);
```

I get this compiler error:

```
error: passing 'const std::vector<int>' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   this->MyVectorOfInts.reserve(NumModels);
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: We need a [MCVE]; I'm guessing you tried to do this in code that declared a `const SimpleClass`, but trying to guess at all the circumstances is not an ideal way to attack this.

Comment: Okay, working on it.

Comment: Seems like you may be calling `this->MyVectorOfInts.reserve(NumModels);` from a `const` member function.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.  I tried to call it from a const function.  Thank you.